# Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'inputs' before initialization

Tags: javascript

```
const inputs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[id]'));

function scheduleMod() {
  $(".wrapper").remove();
  $(".preloader").fadeIn('fast');
  $(".customize").css('display', 'block');
  inputs.forEach(input => {
    const id = input.id;
    const content = localStorage.getItem(id);
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = content;
  })
}

function saveCustom() {
  inputs.forEach(input => {
    const id = input.id;
    const text = input.innerText;
    localStorage.setItem(id, text);
  })
  $('.preloader').fadeOut('slow');
}
```

I used to have this block of code working for tables, but I wanted to replace them with inputs, only to get an error saying `Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'inputs' before initialization`. What does it mean? How do I fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: `saveCustom()` is called before `inputs` is assigned a value. Where is `saveCustom()` called from?

Comment: First of all, `input` elements do not have `innerHTML` not `innerText`.

Comment: I doubt that this is all your code, because I don't see how that could happen here. Please post a minimal, complete example that demonstrates the problem.